# vlookup between 2 Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas Dataframes as follows.

DF1:

```
Security     ISIN
ABC           I1 
DEF           I2
JHK           I3
LMN           I4
OPQ           I5
```

and DF2:

```
ISIN      Value
 I2        100
 I3        200
 I5        300
```

I would like to end up with a third dataframe looking like this:

DF3:

```
Security   Value
 DEF       100
 JHK       200
 OPQ       300
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), by default is inner join, so `how=inner` is omit and if there is only one common column in both `Dataframes`, you can also omit parameter `on='ISIN'`:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2)
#remove column ISIN
df3.drop('ISIN', axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df3)
  Security  Value
0      DEF    100
1      JHK    200
2      OPQ    300
```

Or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) column `ISIN` by `Series` from `df1`:

```
print (df1.set_index('ISIN')['Security'])
ISIN
I1    ABC
I2    DEF
I3    JHK
I4    LMN
I5    OPQ
Name: Security, dtype: object

#create new df by copy of df2
df3 = df2.copy()
df3['Security'] = df3.ISIN.map(df1.set_index('ISIN')['Security'])
#remove column ISIN
df3.drop('ISIN', axis=1, inplace=True)
#change order of columns
df3 = df3[['Security','Value']]
print (df3)
  Security  Value
0      DEF    100
1      JHK    200
2      OPQ    300
```

Comment: thanks again Jazrael. This was extremely helpful. Now, if I am not too cheecky, again, My resulting DF has tree columns and the last 2 have only values as follows:

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) to automatically do an inner join on `ISIN`. The following line of code should get you going:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2)[['Security', 'Value']]
```

Which results in `df3`:

```
  Security  Value
0      DEF    100
1      JHK    200
2      OPQ    300
```

The fully reproducible code sample looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Security': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'JHK', 'LMN', 'OPQ'],
        'ISIN' : ['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5']
    })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Value': [100, 200, 300],
        'ISIN' : ['I2', 'I3', 'I5']
    })

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2)[['Security', 'Value']]
print(df3)
```