# Pandas equivalent to vlookup with a one to many relationship, return one result

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup

I would like to know the pandas alternative to an Excel Vlookup when it involves two dataframes and a one to many relationship.  I have searched for this answer and don't think i found one that solves my use-case.  below are a few post that are relevant, but not exactly what I need.

[Excel VLOOKUP equivalent in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291908/excel-vlookup-equivalent-in-pandas)

[vlookup between 2 Pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993238/vlookup-between-2-pandas-dataframes)

Situation:

I have two data frames and a key that links both (site).  I would use the pandas merge function, but I don't want multiple records returned for one key (location B in this example).

Specifically, I want to return the status of a site from the loc_status dataframe if it exists.  If the location has both a status of "inactive" and "active" then I only want to return "active".

Here is a basic example:

```
loc_status = [{'site':'A', 'status':'ACTIVE'}, {'site':'B',         'status':'ACTIVE'},{'site':'B', 'status':'INACTIVE'},{'site':'C', 'status':'INACTIVE'} ]

loc = [{'site':'A'}, {'site':'B'},{'site':'C'}, {'site':'D'} ]

df_status = pd.DataFrame(loc_status)

+----+-------+----------+
|    | site  |  status  |
+----+-------+----------+
| 0  | A     | ACTIVE   |
| 1  | B     | ACTIVE   |
| 2  | B     | INACTIVE |
| 3  | C     | INACTIVE |
+----+-------+----------+

df_loc = pd.DataFrame(loc)

+------+---+
| site |   |
+------+---+
|   0  | A |
|   1  | B |
|   2  | C |
|   3  | D |
+------+---+

result = [{'site':'A', 'status':'ACTIVE'}, {'site':'B', 'status':'ACTIVE'},{'site':'C', 'status':'INACTIVE'}, {'site': 'D'}]

df_result = pd.DataFrame(result)

+----+-------+----------+
|    | site  |  status  |
+----+-------+----------+
| 0  | A     | ACTIVE   |
| 1  | B     | ACTIVE   |
| 2  | C     | INACTIVE |
| 3  | D     | NaN      |
+----+-------+----------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I appreciate you timing the result vs merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns, so for each site if duplicates `status` always `ACTIVE` is first. Then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with default `keep=first` - get only `ACTIVE` if duplicates.

Last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df_status = df_status.sort_values(['site','status']).drop_duplicates(['site'])
print (df_status)
  site    status
0    A    ACTIVE
1    B    ACTIVE
3    C  INACTIVE

df_loc['status'] = df_loc['site'].map(df_status.set_index('site')['status'])
print (df_loc)
  site    status
0    A    ACTIVE
1    B    ACTIVE
2    C  INACTIVE
3    D       NaN
```

**Timings**:

```
#jezrael solution
In [136]: %timeit df_loc['status_jez'] = df_loc['site'].map(df_status.sort_values(['site','status']).drop_duplicates(['site']).set_index('site')['status'])
10 loops, best of 3: 67.3 ms per loop

#Allen solution
In [137]: %timeit pd.merge(df_loc,df_status.sort_values(['site','status']).groupby(by='site').first().reset_index(),how='left')
10 loops, best of 3: 114 ms per loop

#piRSquared solution
In [138]: %timeit df_loc.assign(status_pir=df_loc.site.map(df_status.loc[(df_status.status == 'ACTIVE').groupby(df_status.site).idxmax()].set_index('site').status))
1 loop, best of 3: 3.37 s per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000
L = np.random.randint(100000,size=N)
df_status = pd.DataFrame({'site': np.random.choice(L, N),
                         'status':np.random.choice(['ACTIVE','INACTIVE'],N)})
print (df_status.head(10))

df_loc = pd.DataFrame({'site':L})
print (df_loc.head(10))
```

Comment: Oops.  I just thanked myself above.  That was meant for you :)

Comment: Glad can help you, nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
#remove Inactive rows if there's an active row for a certain site.
df_status = df_status.sort_values(['site','status']).groupby(by='site').first().reset_index()
#join loc and status df.
pd.merge(df_loc,df_status,how='left')

Out[108]: 
  site    status
0    A    ACTIVE
1    B    ACTIVE
2    C  INACTIVE
3    D       NaN
```

Comment: Hmm, I think you need sort values first - `df_status.sort_values(['site','status']).groupby(by='site').first().reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks that's indeed a potential issue. Just updated my answer.

Comment: No problem, in timings is used your updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Define the `status` series of boolean values determining if `status == 'ACTIVE'`
- Define the `site` series for convenience
- By grouping `status` by `site` and caclulating `idxmax`, I find the fir index that has a `status` of `ACTIVE` if it has one at all.
- With the `idx` I can slice `df_status` with unique values of `site` with the preference for `ACTIVE`
- By setting the index and taking the `status` column, I've created a `pd.Series` which will act `dict` like for the purposes of `map`
- Use `assign` + `map` to create new column

---

```
status = df_status.status == 'ACTIVE'
site = df_status.site
idx = status.groupby(site).idxmax()
m = df_status.loc[idx].set_index('site').status

df_loc.assign(status=df_loc.site.map(m))

  site    status
0    A    ACTIVE
1    B    ACTIVE
2    C  INACTIVE
3    D       NaN
```